Selenium webscraping recaptcha
I want to scrape a website but before that there is a recaptcha and I even got the data using api,and i also injected it into the website as the webpage has no submit button I couldn't submit. the flow is like this if I solve the captcha in the same url the content which is hidden will be displayed. but it is not getting solved. I have searched everywhere. I couldn't find solution. Can anyone help me with this?
Solution and code to the problem

This question is similar to: How can I bypass the Google CAPTCHA with Selenium and Python?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If there is a captcha, you probably shouldn’t be scraping it. The whole idea of a captcha is for bots to not be able to get past it. You might be able to make an AI to detect objects in the images on a reCAPTCHA, but unless you’re into making AIs, it’s probably not worth the effort.
